# How to Remove the Current User email from a dropdown list

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepoint-rest-api, modern-experience, sharepoint-framework

```
const getDropdownDataFromMaster
 = ():
 void =>
 {

    let UserEamilArray = [];

    let userEmail = props.context.pageContext.user.email;

    console.log(userEmail);


    console.log("heyyy");

    props.context.spHttpClient

      .get(

        props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + //(EmployeeEmail eq '${userEmail}')

          `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('UserMaster')/items?$select=*&$filter=viewPublishDocument eq 1`,
        SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
        {
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=nometadata",
            "odata-version": "",
          },
        }
      )
      .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          response.json().then((responseJSON) => {
            responseJSON.value.map((item, index) => {
              let currentUser = `${item.EmployeeEmail}`;
              console.log(currentUser);
              if (currentUser === userEmail) {
                // alert(" Current User in the list " + " " + currentUser);
              }

              let empFstname;
              let empLastname;
              let empEmail;

              if (
                item.EmployeeFirstName == null ||
                item.EmployeeFirstName == ""
              ) {
                empFstname = " ";
              } else {
                empFstname = item.EmployeeFirstName;
              }
              if (
                item.EmployeeLastName == null ||
                item.EmployeeLastName == ""
              ) {
                empLastname = " ";
              } else {
                empLastname = item.EmployeeLastName;
              }
              if (item.EmployeeEmail == null || item.EmployeeEmail == "") {
                empEmail = " ";
              } else {
                empEmail = item.EmployeeEmail;
              }
              console.log(
                item.EmployeeFirstName +
                  " " +
                  item.EmployeeLastName +
                  " " +
                  item.EmployeeEmail
              );
              //state[1,2,3,45,5]
              userName[0].label + userName[0].value;
              // setPublishData((prevFriends) => [
              //   ...prevFriends,
              //   {
              //     ID: item.ID,
              //     DocumentID: item.DocID,
              //     DocumentName: item.DocumentName,
              //     DocumentType: item.DocumentType,
              //     SubmissionDate: item.Created,
              //     SubmissionType: item.SubmissionType,
              //     RequestedBy: item.Username,
              //     Status: item.Status,
              //   },
              // ]);
              // setUserName.filter((n) => {
              //   return n != currentUser;
              // });
              setUserName((prev) => [
                ...prev,
                {
                  label:
                    item.EmployeeFirstName +
                    " " +
                    item.EmployeeLastName +
                    " " +
                    item.EmployeeEmail,
                  value:
                    item.EmployeeFirstName +
                    " " +
                    item.EmployeeLastName +
                    " " +
                    item.EmployeeEmail,
                },
              ]);
            });
          });
        } else {
          response.json().then((responseJSON) => {
            console.log(responseJSON);
            console.log(
              `Something went wrong! Check the error in the browser console.`
            );
            console.log(document.getElementById("selectUservalue")["value"]);
          });
        }

        // console.log([...sel]);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to filter the response array & remove the items with same email as currently logged in user email:

```
const getDropdownDataFromMaster = (): void => {
    let UserEamilArray = [];
    let currentUserEmail = props.context.pageContext.user.email;

    props.context.spHttpClient
        .get(
            props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + //(EmployeeEmail eq '${userEmail}')
            `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('UserMaster')/items?$select=*&$filter=viewPublishDocument eq 1`,
            SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
            {
                headers: {
                    Accept: "application/json;odata=nometadata",
                    "odata-version": "",
                },
            }
        )
        .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
            if (response.ok) {
                response.json().then((responseJSON) => {
                    if (responseJSON.value && responseJSON.value.length) {
                        var filteredResponse = responseJSON.value.filter(function(loopItem){
                            return loopItem.EmployeeEmail != currentUserEmail;
                        });
                        filteredResponse.map((item, index) => {
                            let empFstname;
                            let empLastname;
                            let empEmail;

                            if (
                                item.EmployeeFirstName == null ||
                                item.EmployeeFirstName == ""
                            ) {
                                empFstname = " ";
                            } else {
                                empFstname = item.EmployeeFirstName;
                            }
                            if (item.EmployeeLastName == null || item.EmployeeLastName == "") {
                                empLastname = " ";
                            } else {
                                empLastname = item.EmployeeLastName;
                            }
                            if (item.EmployeeEmail == null || item.EmployeeEmail == "") {
                                empEmail = " ";
                            } else {
                                empEmail = item.EmployeeEmail;
                            }
                            console.log(
                                item.EmployeeFirstName +
                                " " +
                                item.EmployeeLastName +
                                " " +
                                item.EmployeeEmail
                            );
                            userName[0].label + userName[0].value;
                            setUserName((prev) => [
                                ...prev,
                                {
                                    label:
                                        item.EmployeeFirstName +
                                        " " +
                                        item.EmployeeLastName +
                                        " " +
                                        item.EmployeeEmail,
                                    value:
                                        item.EmployeeFirstName +
                                        " " +
                                        item.EmployeeLastName +
                                        " " +
                                        item.EmployeeEmail,
                                },
                            ]);
                        });
                    }
                });
            } else {
                response.json().then((responseJSON) => {
                    console.log(responseJSON);
                    console.log(
                        `Something went wrong! Check the error in the browser console.`
                    );
                    console.log(document.getElementById("selectUservalue")["value"]);
                });
            }

            // console.log([...sel]);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
};
```

---

You can also filter the list items while fetching it using API. Use filter query like below:

```
let currentUserEmail = props.context.pageContext.user.email;

props.context.spHttpClient
    .get(
        props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + //(EmployeeEmail eq '${userEmail}')
        `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('UserMaster')/items?$select=*&$filter=viewPublishDocument eq 1 and EmployeeEmail ne '${currentUserEmail}'`,
        SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
        {
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json;odata=nometadata",
                "odata-version": "",
            },
        }
    )
```